# why do i have to rebuild the test project, whenever i change the code?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I have visual studio 2010, and a unit-test project.
when i run (debug test in the current context),then stop it,and then change the code,

i have to rebuild the project, otherwise the project will run without debugging, and it will use the old code !!!

why is that happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the tests needs a compiled version of the code, since they need to execute your code to test whether it works or not.

Edit: in my environment, the test project is in the same solution. Running the test will automatically rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

When you 'run' the code you are running a compiled executable. When you change the code this does not change the compiled executable (i.e. you have to 'rebuild' it).

Comment: This assumes that the tested code is statically linked to the test-code. The OP is asking why he has to rebuild the test project.

Comment: even if the code was dynamically linked wouldn't he still need to recompile the code for the object he changed?

Comment: Ok, Marm0t but can it be just as simple as the ordinary project??  i mean you can change the code while your debugging?and BTW i mean change the test code, not the tested code.